# how to select data from multiple tables with linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables :

```
- Projects
   ID
   ProjectName
   Areas
   PaymentSystem

- ProjectDetails
   DetailsID
   ProjectDetailName 
   ProjectDetailImage
   ProjectID
```

these tables has one to one relation i want to select all project with project details that matches the id i wrote this query but not work :

```
var query = from p in context.Projects
                  join pd in context.ProjectDetails
                   on p.ID equals pd.ProjectID

                    select new
                    {
                        Project=p,
                        ProjectDetail=pd
                    };
        GVAllProjects.DataSource = query.ToList();
        GVAllProjects.DataBind();
```

this is the error message i have after bind data :

> DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[Project, App_Code.nvgnvnbf, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ProjectDetail, App_Code.nvgnvnbf, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.

Comment: `but not work` - That's not helpful. What happens? Error message?

Comment: i am sorry this is the error message `DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[Project, App_Code.nvgnvnbf, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ProjectDetail, App_Code.nvgnvnbf, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.`

Comment: Your code is returning all ids.  You would need a 'where'to limit the results to only one id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement is not specifying enough detail in what you want. Project=p does not tell what column in p or pd (which are an alias you defined for your select) to grab and place into your anonymous object.

If you want the entire object, you are going to run into performance problems depending on how many objects you are taking, especially if you do not need all the information

You must specify what you want such as

```
                select new
                {
                    ProjectId=p.Id,
                    ProjectDetailID=pd.DetailsId
                };
```

One way to Handle this would to create a View model class and then utilize that in the select new clause of the linq statement.

For example your view model should look like

```
public class DetailedProjectView
{
    public int ProjectId {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Project> MainProjects {get;set;} // Not Required
    public IEnumerable<ProjectDetails> MainProjectDetails {get;set;}
}
```

Then you use this class in your linq statement to select the key:value pairs into a new view model object

```
var query = from p in context.Projects
                select new DetailedProjectView
                {
                    ProjectId=p.Id,
                    ProjectDetails= (from pd in context.ProjectDetails
                                    where  pd.Id == p.Id
                                    select new DetailedProjectView 
                                    {
                                     ProjectId = pd.Id
                                     MainProjectDetails = select new ProjectDetails{ ProjectName = pd.ProjectDetailName}
                                    }
                };
```